# How to simulate a sheet of paper in Blender Game Engine?

Tags: game-engine, physics

I am trying to simulate the physics for a sheet of paper in Blender Game Engine.
For this, I am using an ordinary plane (subdivided in several faces). I tried doing this by defining soft body physics for the plane, but I can't seem to get the physics parameters right. Mostly, it's possible to let the plane behave a bit like a more stiff cloth, but not like paper.
Is it possible to get the physics parameters right to simulate paper, or is soft body not the right way to go and I should try something completely different?

Comment: @stacker in the game engine there are no presets.

Comment: @maddin45 Ouch, I overlooked the BGE tag

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The biggest problem I see here is that the softbody algorithms in the game engine are not physically correct, they are only made to look plausible and be fast. Especially the stiffness of softbodies depends on the mesh resolution: higher subdivision results in less stiffness.

A setup that looks fine for paper is a plane with just a few subdivisions

[image]

and the following Softbody settings

[image]

Make sure you disable `Shape Match` since this seems not to work with flat objects. Also make sure `Bending Constraints` are enabled. Otherwise the paper can just fold along the edges with no resistance. Also increase the `Margin` so that collisions will be detected correctly. Be aware however that this will make your paper float slightly above the ground.

This is what the resulting paper looks like when falling onto the ground:

[image]

One thing that is still missing however is air drag. Maybe you can simulate that using a [Force field constraint actuator](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Game_Engine/Logic/Actuators/Constraint) but I have not found out how they work yet.