# Animation of falling paper in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, physics, soft-body

I want to animate the falling sheet, i.e. swinging oneself and falling with zigzag. Is there some modifier which would let me get the more realistic effect than normal appointing the motion path manually?

Similar effect was described in this topic: [How to simulate a sheet of paper in Blender Game Engine?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23223/how-to-simulate-a-sheet-of-paper-in-blender-game-engine) but I want to use Cycles render and I cannot fit appropriate settings.

[image: soft body settings]

Answer (score 7):

You can use force fields to obtain this kind of effects, specially '*wind*' and '*vortex*'.

[image]

**But I did not succeed the zigzag you mentioned**

The paper is a soft body, with no particular parameters.

Then add some force fields and tune them..., for instance this kind of configuration, where :

- Strength and flow allows to create an air flow at the given strength
- Noise and seed add some randomness to the flow
- Power and min/max defines a falloff of the field

[image]

[image]

I don't know if the zigzag is possible with a paper in real.. but anyway, as said before, I did not succeed to turn that into a zigzag...

Hope this help however.

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot. It isn't exactly this effect which I wanted to get, but it much helped. Maybe I didn't specify earlier - I thought about dynamics of the stiffer, small sheet (so like e.g. leaflet), which is changing his shape only a bit while falling down in the characteristic zigzag way - but I hope that thanks to your method I can also get something similar to this.