# Smoke collision

Tags: modifiers, rigging, smoke-simulation

I have a smoke simulation that I'm trying to get a wing to flap away.

I have domain smoke setup from a fractal plane with random faces that are deleted.

And I put a smoke collision physic on my rigged 3d model  (on the mesh, couldn't put it on the rig )

The smoke is getting flapped away but it is barely noticeable.

Is there a way to modify the smoke collision on the mesh to were it really flaps away the smoke more intensely or make it more noticeable or just have it flap away more smoke?

Or is this caused by too many faces from the smoke simulation?

Open for any thoughts or suggestions

Comment: A wing as collision object will collide with the smoke but will not displace any air, as it would happen in the real world. Probably you need to add some kind of force field like wind or vortex  and animate it to make this work.

Comment: Should I add that to the smoke or to the obj or the rig?

Comment: Force fields (like wind) are a different kind of object read about them here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/force_fields/index.html?highlight=force%20field

Comment: Read It. I still do not understand :/

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W1B4SY9JDzw

Comment: Got further along. But I still cannot get the wind up interact with the smoke for some reason

Comment: I said "for some reason " because I do not know what is causing the issue. And yes I will add more details

Comment: Look at this link, maybe it relates to your project: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/61804/1853