# physics : blow sheets of paper with wind?

Tags: modifiers, physics

I need to create an animated shot where sheets of paper would be blown away by some (directional) wind, like you would do with leaves :

[image: blow leaves]

I'm hesitating between animating it by hand (using curve modifiers on my sheets) or with physics.  It should be quite realistic.

Would you consider doing it with physics, or is it just too much work ?
If yes, how would you do it ?

Thanks !

Comment: Don't know if it is realistic enough, but https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58582/animation-of-falling-paper-in-cycles/58606#58606

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68549/how-to-animate-falling-feathers/68561#68561

Answer (score 0):

It depends in how many sheets you'll have in your scene, and what type of animation you want to do.

If it's a realistic animation, then I'll prefer physics and work on my simulation enough to bake it (it wont be that heavy then)

If it's a cartoonish animation with few sheets, then the curve method could be fun, but it's not the fast option here.

Curious to see what others think about it !

Comment: Let's say about 30 sheets.  You think working with physics could be faster here ?  I'm afraid that it takes a lot of time to tweak.

Comment: Sir this is not an answer ...